# Display custom field if it exists and has a specific value

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to display the post title if the custom field exists and has a value of apple...

```
<?php if ( isset ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mycustomvalue', true ) ) ) && if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mycustomvalue', true ) == 'apple' ) : ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
```

I am getting a white screen, anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into `the_title()` to alter the output.

In functions.php paste this:

```
function my_change_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $custom_title = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mycustomvalue', true);

    if( isset($custom_title) && $custom_title == 'apple' )
        return $custom_title;

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'my_change_title', 10, 2);
```

In your template, you can just use `<?php the_title(); ?>`

---

To use your custom value in your template:

```
<?php $custom_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mycustomvalue', true); ?>
<?php if( isset($custom_value) && $custom_value == "apple" ) : ?>
    Do something
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the_title was just being used as an example of some content being returned,  I am not actually using the_title

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this is what you need.

Comment: Hi rob, with the first line, if mycustomvalue doesn't exist then won't it display a notice to that effect?

Comment: Nope =) `get_post_meta` returns an empty string or empty array when nothing found and in the if statement you check if the var `isset`

Answer (score 0):

Because, in your code you didn't close the IF condition.

I have modified your code but NOT tested.

```
<?PHP
$post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mycustomvalue', true);
if( !empty( $post_meta ) && $post_meta == 'apple'){
    the_title();
}
?>
```

NOTE: if you don't want pass the third parameter, you will get the result as an array and you have to change your code from `!empty( $post_meta )` to `count( $post_meta ) > 0`